# Creating project in Android 5.0 Lollipop using Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, api, sdk

I have updated all 5.0 related packages in SDK Manager and when i create a new project in Eclipse it showing target version as 4.X (L Preview) instead of 5.0! Cna anyone help me to resolve this issue in Eclipse. And also I'm not getting the appcompat_v21 for lower API levels support!

[image]

[image]

Edit: Added screenshot of SDK Manager Tools.

[image]

Comment: did u restarted eclipse?

Comment: Yeah daily I'm restarting it. But no use at all!

Comment: make sure ur sdk path is correct , i could update it properly

Comment: Even i checked all these. Everything is perfect! SDK Path, Java, All latest updates everything is fine.

Comment: Could you put screen shot of Android SDK manager with Tools details

Comment: As you requested @Palak I have added screenshot of SDK Manager Tools section.

Comment: The scenario that you are facing is same in my case too but once I create the project with `4.X (L Preview)`, it creates the `appcompat` library too and in the project explorer shows as `android 5`. As you mentioned, there is no option to select material theme. May be a bug.

Comment: @SpringBreaker But for me appcompat_v21 is not creating! For u it's creating v21 or v7?

Comment: @KevinChris: It creates a v7 library.

Comment: Same problem, still no one who has an answer that fixes this?

Answer (score 6):

You can change your project to 5.0 after creating the project from the properties...

```
Right click project --> Properties --> Android --> Select Android 5.0 from project build path.
```

Comment: Thumbs up for this @Achuthan and I know this will do the job pretty well. But this didn't solve my problem. Here problem is when I create a project I will select the 5.0 which prompts me to select the Material Themes and when I create project it should automatically create appcompat_v21 in workspace. If i do like as you suggest i can change the theme in 'styles.xml' but where i can get appcompat_v21 for lower versions api?